# How to prevent User to enter value at maxlength using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, maxlength, disabled-input

I want that user should not be able to enter text if he has more then 5 comma separated values in input box.

I have reached the value, but not sure. I think `maxlength` dynamic should do the trick.

I am trying to apply below code, but not working -

```
require(["jquery"],function($) {
    $("input.toEmail").keyup(function(e){
        var inputEmail = $("input.toEmail").val();
        var count = (inputEmail.match(/,/g) || []).length;  
        if(count >= 5){
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Is this `test,sdfds,dsf,dsf,sdf,dsf dsfsdf dsfdsf` valid according to your validation? Here there are only 5 comma. Would you allow space?

Comment: @MayankPatel No worries, I will check the space thing myself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve it in this simple way.

Note:

- Use [split](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) to `"Split a string into an array of substrings"`
- Use [slice](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_string.asp) to `"extracts parts of a string and returns the extracted parts in a new string"`
- Use [join](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) to `"returns the array as a string"`

```js
$("input.toEmail").keyup(function(e){
        var inputEmail = $(this).val();
        var strArray = inputEmail.split(/,/g);
     
        if(strArray.length >= 5){
            this.value = strArray.slice(0, 5).join(',');
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input  type="text" class="toEmail"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Again, this worked but doesn't work if someone ctrl+V like jhgsd,f,sdf,sdf,sdfsdfsdfs

Comment: You can test by ctrl + V `jhgsd,f,sdf,sdf,sdfsdfsdfs,` . And the result will be `jhgsd,f,sdf,sdf,sdfsdfsdfs`. So it worked fine for me.

Comment: Ok, this is strange. The code works here fine. You are right, but when I paste it in my code I get following error when I am pasting new string - ReferenceError: strArray is not defined

Comment: It just a syntax error. You should declare `strArray` variable first.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you want to restrict to 6 comma restricted values hence it will include 5 commas. What I am doing here is that you can replace last(6th) comma
so that it will allow only 6 values.

```js
$(function() {
    $("input.toEmail").keyup(function(e){
       var length_comma = (($(this).val().match(/,/g)||[]).length)
        if(length_comma >= 6){          
          this.value = this.value.replace(/,\s*$/, "");
          e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="toEmail" type="text" name="toEmail" />
```

Comment: This code worked but didn't worked if someone copy paste

Comment: Please note that the code does not work when you press and hold comma's keyboard button.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [keypress](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/) instead of keyup.

```
$("input.toEmail").keypress(function(e) {
  var inputEmail = $("input.toEmail").val();
  var count = (inputEmail.match(/,/g) || []).length;
  if (count >= 5) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This is no tested code, but you may get the idea. Basically you set the content of you input back to the previous state if you reach the limit.

```
...
var inputEmail = $("input.toEmail").val();
var inputLength = inputEmail.length;

...

if (count >= 5) {
    $("input.toEmail").val(inputEmail.substring(0, inputLength - 1); // write back the previous content
}
```

Comment: And how this code is taking into consideration commas as OP wants?

Comment: @mitkosoft I thought the OP already solved the problem of the commas. That's why I just posted what's new and leave out his working code. That's why the `...` placeholders.